# Do MySQL/InnoDB stats tables persist through major version upgrades?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, upgrade

After performing a major version upgrade of a PostgreSQL database, the `ANALYZE` command needs to be run in order to repopulate tables for query statistics, which do not persist through the upgrade. Until the stats tables are repopulated, query performance can be severely degraded.

Do the statistics tables for MySQL databases using the InnoDB engine persist through major version upgrades?

Do you need to run `ANALYZE` or a similar command after a major version upgrade in order to improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of about 5.6, the "statistics" have been reasonably well maintained.  Every query starts by collecting statistics *if needed*.

MySQL comes close to making "statistics" a no-brainer.  Just run your queries; it will almost always "do a good job".

Any statistics that are persisted are kept with the data.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether they persist or not, it is always a good idea to update statistics after a major version upgrade (of any database, not just MySQL). The structure of system tables and views might change; there may be additional metrics collected by the new version; there may be bug fixes in the statistics analyzer; there may be changes in the physical implementation of various database objects that require updated statistics.